# Images as answers

Tags: discussion

Is posting an image as an answer okay? E.g.: https://economics.stackexchange.com/a/8535/1601

 In this [meta question](https://economics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1365/images-as-questions) it is agreed that images are unwelcome as questions because they are not searchable. Is it safe to assume that people will try to find their own question (since they cannot be sure of the answer) and hence answers do not have to searchable?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

My interpretation is that images are unwelcome (in questions or answers) when they contain *only* text and are used because posters are simply unwilling to retype the material themselves.

The posting of images to represent genuinely graphical concepts (plots, game trees, etc.) are okay because SE doesn't provide a sensible alternative for presenting this information.

Usually, I would expect some text to accompany a figure answer because it is often hard to interpret a figure without an explanation of why it addresses the question.

Others may have different views.

Comment: The images should also be given alt texts.

Comment: @curiousdannii Yes, alt text is important because it will make Econ.SE more accessible to community members with visual impairments who should not be excluded if avoidable.